# Link in master page visible for only certain users

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd like to add links to the main menu (master page) that are visible only for certain users. I did this for a folder through a Web.Config file with

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="User1" />
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

What is the equivalent for links in the master page?
I already know about the Anonymous and LoggedInTemplate but they don't work for me since I'd like the link to be visible only for given users.

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms website and I'm using C#.

*FYI, I'm a beginner and setting up Roles, Membership and such would be a problem for me since I'm using VS 2013 and it doesn't have the [Website Administration Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228053(v=vs.140).aspx) built-in. That's why I decided to manually specify the users, since there wont be many users (5 at max)*

Comment: Web Configuration Tool? Are you referring to ASP.NET Provider Page or whatever?..

Comment: I'm referring to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Comment: Perhaps you should read this article: [Thinktecture.IdentityManager as a replacement for the ASP.NET WebSite Administration tool](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ThinktectureIdentityManagerAsAReplacementForTheASPNETWebSiteAdministrationTool.aspx).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Yeah, exactly what I thought you were referring to.. I haven't used that tool since VS 2003..

Comment: IdentityManager would be a nice alternative, but is there any beginners tutorial for it?

Comment: @WhatWhatWhat If you want to reply to me, make sure you use the "@Mason" syntax so it'll ping me, otherwise I may never know you responded (I just happened by chance to check back on this question). The link I provided has some basics, and the Thinktecture.IdentityManager GitHub site that Hanselman links to also contains getting started info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" id="SpecialAdminOnlyPanel">
My links are <a href="#">here.</a>
</asp:Panel>
```

Code behind

```
List<string> AllowedUsers = new List<string>(){"Larry","Moe","Curly"};

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        if(!AllowedUsers.Contains(User.Identity.Name))
        {
            SpecialAdminOnlyPanel.Visible=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Put your links in a panel, then hide/show them with the `.Visible` property. The contents of the panel won't be sent to the client at all. I personally think this is an inelegant solution.

You could probably create a new custom server control similar to `LoginView` but have it accept a comma separated list of user names. But it's been a while since I've created a new control (my mind is on MVC now) so we'll have to leave that to someone else. The use of such a hypothetical tool might look like this, with a nice declarative syntax:

```
<myn:SelectiveContentShower>
    <myn:UserGroup users="Larry,Moe,Curly">
        My links are <a href="#">here.</a>
    </myn:UserGroup>
<myn:SelectiveContentShower>
```

Comment: naturally, the question to follow your snippet is.. what is `User` in this `context`..

Comment: HttpContext.User; how is it populated?

Comment: @BrettCaswell No, I wouldn't think someone would ask that. Every page has a [User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: @BrettCaswell That's outside the scope of the question. He clearly has users working since he states he used web.config's authorization stuff. It's probably Windows authentication or something like that. Anyways, the question wasn't about how to set up users, only how to hide/show content based on the user.

Comment: I get an error on the User: "..does not exist in the current context"
Should I add some using System... ?

Comment: Adding Page. in front of User.Identity.Name fixed my problem

Comment: @WhatWhatWhat You can either do that, or add `using System.Web.UI;` to the top of your class (it's there by default when you create a new page).

Comment: Thank you mason and Brett. Quick question, can I make the List public and put it in the namespace so I could use it across all classes and functions?

Comment: @WhatWhatWhat Yes, probably make it `public static`. And put it in a namespace like `MyApplication` and in a class called `UserAuthentication` and then access it via `MyApplication.UserAuthentication.AllowedUsers`. I've done that for several simple business apps I've done where I didn't want to bother with the whole roles/membership setup.

Comment: @mason, how would I use the same string in a web.config file for a folder? For the allowed users="theStringHere"

Comment: @WhatWhatWhat You'd put it in [app settings](http://odetocode.com/articles/345.aspx).